# PC didn't boot from sleep and fans were still running

Tags: boot, battery, sleep

After my PC went into sleep mode, the fans kept running, which never happened to me. I tried to wake it up by pressing the power button, as usual, but it didn't boot. After reconnecting the power supply, it booted again.
I suspected a CMOS battery failure, I checked the voltage and it said 3.2 Volts, which seems right to me. However, my mouse lags sometimes which, as far as I'm concerned, can be a sign for a battery failure too. So, do I need to switch my cmos battery or do I just need to do something like a bios update?

Comment: If a mouse lags this can be caused by a weak battery but not the CMOS battery but the battery in the wireless mouse.

Comment: Reset your power management settings. The suspend function may not be working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a good chance that the two problems you indicated
are separate and not connected.

A mouse problem can be diagnosed by trying another mouse.
Mice can easily be replaced.

You could Reset or update the BIOS (thus losing all your settings).

If this doesn't help, then try some software checks.
To test Windows integrity, run
[Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
and then
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
If you mouse has a driver from the manufacturer, look for a
newer version.

If nothing is found, then you might be facing a hardware problem.
Rather than spending money on replacing parts that may not be the source
of the problem, it might be preferable for a professional to have
a look at your computer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try a bios update, I checked and it's not really up-to-date